# PHP count values with same id

Tags: php, mysql

My current project: I'm trying to create an overview of all cars in a company.

I get the following mysql result table:

```
|car_id|distance|
|   1  |  33875 |
|   1  |  33027 |
|   1  |  31579 |
|   2  | 125636 |
|   2  | 124937 |
```

The "Distance" is the mileage after a fill up.

**What do I need?**

I need the total distance for each car.

The result should look like:

```
|car_id|distance|
|   1  |  2296  | (33875 - 31579)
|   2  |   699  | (125636 - 124937)
```

Comment: Could you please share with us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do it with `group by` clause, e.g.:

```
SELECT id, (MAX(distance) - MIN(distance)) AS mileage
FROM cars
GROUP BY id;
```

Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94296a/2/0).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Darshan's answer:

```
select id, (max(distance) - min(distance)) as mileage
, concat('(',min(distance),' - ',max(distance),')') as distance
from cars
group by id;
```