# PHP MySQL Join Tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

I want to program an overview that shows all the cars in a company. Using the mileage and the number of liters to determine how high the consumption of each car is. I have 2 MySQL tables: cars & fuel. In cars all cars are stored with mark ect. and in fuel the individual refueling processes are stored. I have already a PHP Function, that calculates the consumption.

```
    $array = array(
    '0' => array(
        'date' => '14.12.',
        'km' => 167328,
        'liter' => 64.72
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'date' => '15.12.',
        'km' => 166678,
        'liter' => 69.26
    ),
    '2' => array(
        'date' => '16.12.',
        'km' => 166778,
        'liter' => 68.26
    ),
    '3' => array(
        'date' => '17.12.',
        'km' => 166808,
        'liter' => 45.26
    )
);

function get_km( $x, $y ) {
    $km = $x - $y;
    return $km;
}

function consumption( $x, $y ) {
    $csmpt = $x / $y;
    return round( $csmpt );
}

function calculate( $x ) {
    $y = count( $x );
    if ( $y < 3 ) {
        $consumption= consumption( get_km( array_values( $x )[0]['km'], array_values( $x )[1]['km'] ), array_values( $x )[0]['liter'] );
        return $consumption . ' Liter / 100km';
    }

    $km = get_km( array_values( $x )[0]['km'], array_values( $x )[$y-1]['km'] );
    for( $i = 0; $i < $y; $i++ ) {
        $sum += array_values( $x )[$i]['liter'];
        $consumption += consumption( $km, $sum );
    }
    echo $consumption . ' Liter / 100km';

    // Return the consumption
    return;
}

echo calculate( $array );
```

Car Table:
|id|type|license|

Fuel Table:
|id|date|km|liter|car_id|

[Click here for preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b20Og.jpg)

So how can I join this 2 tables together?

Comment: Protip: don't use `id` in your table for your primary key like that. It gets too confusing as to which table field you're referencing

Comment: I think `from CarTable at ct left join FuelTable as ft on ft.car_id = ct.id` would do it.

Comment: Did your previous question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516012/php-count-values-with-same-id, get resolved?

Comment: @christ85 I think you mean "from CarTable as ct.."

Comment: @MichaelEugeneYuen Ah, yea, wrong key there, opps.